# Last hour cheeking in php

Tags: php

I trying to disabled the button when the time left last 2 hour, below is my code, but it always go to else.How can i solve this problem?

```
$last_hour = strtotime('-2 hour', $auction['Item_Expired']); 

     if ($auction['Item_Expired']  >= $last_hour) {

                           echo '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled id="agreeButton" data-dismiss="modal">Agree</button>';
                        } else {
                              echo '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="agreeButton" data-dismiss="modal">Agree</button>';
                        } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$last_hour = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hours', strtotime($auction['Item_Expired'])));

      $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

      if ($date >= $last_hour) {

          echo '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled data-dismiss="modal">Agree</button>';
      }else{

          echo '  <button type="button" id ="agreeBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Agree</button>';
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the logic of what you are doing.

You are passing `Item_Expired` timestamp as the relative starting point of `strtotime` and than you compare with `Item_Expired`.

I think you should compare with `now()`